# How to filter datadog logs by multiple tags using dashboard template variable?

Tags: datadog

I want to be able to easily create Datadog dashboards with log-based widgets restricted to a subset of tag values in Datadog. Currently, I have to hard-code the list of possible tag values in each widget.

```
service:(service-a OR service-b OR service-c)
```

When a new tag value is added, or a tag from the collection is renamed, I have to manually edit every widget.

I'd like to create a template variable that can be referenced as that list instead of hard coding.

The following hasn't worked:

```
# with $services.value -> "service-a OR service-b OR service-c"
service:($services.value)

# with $services.value -> "(service-a OR service-b OR service-c)"
service:$services.value
```

And [Datadog's search syntax docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/search_syntax/) don't have clues.

How can I define a list of "OR" tag values for a log widget via template variable?

*Bonus points if the answer includes a way to customize that list from the variable dropdown checkboxes.*

Answer (score -2):

You need to create variables on your dashboard.

Then, when looking at the dashboard, you will then have dropdowns where you can select one or more values (below the dashboard title). This is also where you can edit the available variables and add new ones.

[image: Tag dropdown]

This is an example of the edit/add GUI for variables.
Notice that you can set a default, and also limit which options are selectable. Though the latter I have never used.

[image: edit var GUI]

You can give the variable a different name, though I advise you to use the name of what you are using for clarity (service in your case)

Then you can use it in your query, tough, compared to what you already wrote, without a dot. As the variable is already a value.

[image: query usage of variable]

Comment: Thank you for answering. This question is specifically about defining a variable that allows for a list of "OR" values, which seems to be less straightforward (at best) than just using a basic variable like you are showing here.

Comment: As far as I know, as soon as you select multiple in the same dropdown, it is a list of OR values.

Comment: That is true for comma separated lists, like you can use in metrics, but it is not true for OR separated lists in logs.